# how to merge Two datasets with different time ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-merge

I have two datasets that look like this:

`df1`:

| Date | City | State | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | Chicago | IL | 35 |
| 2019-01 | Orlando | FL | 322 |
| ... | .... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | Chicago | IL | 334 |
| 2021-07 | Orlando | FL | 4332 |

`df2`:

| Date | City | State | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-03 | Chicago | IL | 30 |
| 2020-03 | Orlando | FL | 319 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | Chicago | IL | 331 |
| 2021-07 | Orlando | FL | 4000 |

My `date` is in format `period[M]` for both datasets. I have tried using the `df1.join(df2,how='outer')` and `(df2.join(df1,how='outer')` commands but they don't add up correctly, essentially, in `2019-01`, I have sales for `2020-03`. How can I join these two datasets such that my output is as follows:

I have not been able to use `merge()` because I would have to merge with a combination of `City` and `State` and `Date`

| Date | City | State | Quantity | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | Chicago | IL | 35 | NaN |
| 2019-01 | Orlando | FL | 322 | NaN |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | Chicago | IL | 334 | 331 |
| 2021-07 | Orlando | FL | 4332 | 4000 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `outer-merge`. By not specifying the columns to merge on, you merge on the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames (in this case, `Date`, `City` and `State`).

```py
out = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').sort_values(by='Date')
```

Output:

```py
      Date     City State  Quantity   Sales
0  2019-01  Chicago    IL      35.0     NaN
1  2019-01  Orlando    FL     322.0     NaN
4  2020-03  Chicago    IL       NaN    30.0
5  2020-03  Orlando    FL       NaN   319.0
2  2021-07  Chicago    IL     334.0   331.0
3  2021-07  Orlando    FL    4332.0  4000.0
```